# Pass Value as Parameter from View Controller to Method of Entity Class

Tags: ios, uitextfield, parameter-passing

I have a ViewController with a UITextField. The user enters a string of characters into the textField, clicks a done button and then this value should be passed to a method in the entity class. I know I need to pass this value as a parameter but I'm getting stuck.

I've tried to pass this value by adding a parameter to the end of the clickDone IBAction for the done button with no luck. Thank you for even the smallest bit of help or point into the right direction.

```
- (IBAction)doneClicked:(NSString*) name {
...
}
```

I've tried creating an ivar for ViewController in my entity class h file but Xcode asks "Unknown type name 'ViewController'; did you mean UIViewController?

```
@interface EntityClass : NSManagedObject{
ViewController* refVC;
UITextField* textBox;
}
```

and then use

```
self.name = self.refVC.textBox.text;
```

in my method in entity class m file to return the NSString self.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. This is my final code. It works. Help is no longer needed.

Thanks!

```
- (IBAction)doneClicked:(NSString*) name {
...

superClass.name = headingText.text;  //headingText is UITextField on ViewController

[superClass doSomething];
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the ViewController to the Entity Object. Instead, update the entity object's property in your doneClicked action.

```
- (IBAction)doneClicked:(NSString *)name {
   myObject.name = name;
}
```

Comment: But can you pass a value through a parameter if the IBAction occurs when a button is clicked?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the way you're passing ViewController into the entity object is wrong and also violates the MVC separation (you're mixing UI and data model).

Comment: It was the way it was suggested on another stack overflow QA...I'm asking b/c it crashing b/c it's says it's passing a rectangular button and I ran across another forum that said not to pass a parameter on an IBAction that runs when a button is clicked.